# an example of a simple ring which is not a division ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I was thinking about a simple ring and I found a question that every simple ring is a division ring. I think this is not a correct theorem and I want to find an example.

Comment: If you have trouble finding what was wrong with your proof, you could append it to the end of your post so that we could help you find the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A matrix ring over a field $M_n(F)$ is simple but not a division ring for $n>1$.

I think another different example is furnished by infinite dimensional Clifford algebras. If you have a real, infinite dimensional vector space $V$ with a nondegenerate symmetric bilinear form $B$, I think that $C\ell(V,B)$ is a simple not-Artinian ring that isn't a domain.

[Weyl algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_algebra) are simple domains which are not usually division rings. If I read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_algebra) right, Weyl algebras can be thought of as Clifford algebras using symplectic forms rather than symmetric ones.

*Commutative* simple rings are all fields, so if that is what you proved, you are fine.